# WPF ChildWindow ResizeMode

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit, wpf-4.0

I'm developing an xbap application that is a partial trust application with Internet zone permissions.  For security reasons I can not show a Window and as I result I am stuck with using the ChildWindow as my modal window that is part of the WPFToolkit.  I'm looking into how the user can resize the childwindow with a maximize button and also resizing by dragging the edges/corners of the window.

How do implement a ChildWindow.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.CanResizeWithGrip simialr to the standard Window control?  I've tried Xceeds WPF Toolkit as well.  According to the documentation it's implementation of the ChildWindow has a ResizeMode public property (http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ChildWindow).  But this is not the case as get ResizeMode is not defined compile time error and intellisense does not show it as a property either.

Is there an easy way to implement this feature or a free class library that has this functionality?

Comment: XBAP is pretty much deprecated due to these very same issues. Have you considered going standard WPF instead?

Comment: All the higher ups really like the idea of it being in a browser.  It gives them the warm fuzzy feeling that they can use it anywhere even though they can only use on windows with IE/Firefox.  I think part of the sell was that it was an browser based application.  It was started over 5 years ago right when I think WPF/Silverlight came out.  I've been told it was started with WPF because Silverlight 1.0 was missing so many controls.  At any rate it is what it is an xbap application and don't have much say in that.

Comment: This application has lot more functionality than what is possible with HTML 4 (5 years ago).  I suppose it could have been done but would have been a pretty ugly code base filled with lots of JavaScript.  The docking controls are one part that would seem difficult to do with JavaScript/HTML 4.  It really is a windows WPF application but it’s front end is through the browser and not the desktop.